# Unable to access attributes from `e.target` with a contentEditable element

Tags: reactjs, input, contenteditable

I have an `h1` element in my React app that I plan to use with a `contentEditable` attribute to allow users to edit it directly. The problem is within the `useFormValues` hook that I use to manage all my other inputs, we are unable to access the `e.target.name` or `e.target.value` properties the way we are with a standard input. [Note: Please don't comment just to recommend I stick with a standard input, I've already weighed the pros and cons].

When I log the following `console.log(Object.entries(e.target));` I get this array:
[image: Array]

The second of these items contains my object along with its properties, but I'm wondering why this doesn't come directly from `e.target`. It feels incorrect and risky to access `e.target.name` with `e.target[1][1].name`.

Relevant code below, starting with the `h1` here:

```
        <RecipeName
            data-test="recipePage-name"
            length={recipe.recipe.name.length}
            contentEditable={editable}
            onInput={handleChange}
            name="name"
            value={values.name || recipe.recipe.name}
            suppressContentEditableWarning={true}
          >
            {recipe.recipe.name}
          </RecipeName>
```

And the hook:

```
const handleChange = e => {
    e.persist();
    let tmp = { ...values };
    let value;
    switch (e.target.type) {
      case 'number':
        value = parseInt(e.target.value);
        break;
      case 'file':
        value = e.target.files[0];
        break;
      case 'contenteditable':
        value = e.target.innerHTML;
        break;
      default:
        value = e.target.value;
    }
    dot.str(e.target.name, value, tmp);
    setValues(tmp);
  };
```

Update: In the end I decided to switch to a different function to ensure I didn't collide too much with the `handleChange` functionality. Here's what I have now:

```
const handleContentEditable = (e) => {
    e.persist();
    let tmp = { ...values };
    let name = e.target.dataset.name;
    let type = e.target.dataset.type;
    let value = e.target.innerHTML.replace(/(<br[^>]>|<br>|&nbsp;|\n|\r|\t)+/gi, "");
    if (type === 'numeric') {
      if (isNaN(String.fromCharCode(e.nativeEvent.which))) {
        e.preventDefault()
      };
      value = e.target.innerHTML.replace(/\D/g,'');
    }
    dot.str(name, value, tmp);
    setValues(tmp);
  }
```

The problem, as I noted in a comment below, is that while I am successfully preventing users from typing any characters that are non-numeric, I am also preventing them from using "select all" by CTRL+A because A is non-numeric. Is there any way around this? Like sensing whether two keys are pressed simultaneously.

Comment: Can you show the implementation of `RecipeName` in a code sandbox or somewhere else?

Comment: It's just an `h1` wrapped in a styled-component, there's no implementation beyond what you see here.

Comment: `<h1>` is not an input thus does not have a "value" as in `e.target.value` but only inner html or textcontent

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss What would be the correct way to turn this `h1` into a controlled React component then? It needs to update the same `values` array that the other inputs use.

Answer (score 1):

Let's go with basic JavaScript and demonstrate some issues with the type, value etc. I made lots of comments in the code using `console.log()` to show what is what.

I will leave the reactjs conversion exercise to the OP here.

```js
function handleChange(event) {
  console.log('we are here');
  // not a function:
  //event.persist();
  //let tmp = { ...values };
  let value;

  console.log("Target:", event.target); // the h1 element
  console.log("Target:name", event.target.name); // undefined
  console.log("What:", event.type); // "input"
  console.log("CTarg:", event.currentTarget); // same as target but might not be for delegated events or elements wrapped
  console.log("New:", event.data); //last character entered for an h1
  console.log("ETarget type:", event.target.type); // undefined
  console.log("Target tag:", event.target.tagName.toLowerCase()); //h1
  console.log("Targ cont:", event.currentTarget.textContent); // what it is
  console.log("Targ html:", event.currentTarget.innerHTML); // if <p> entered returns &lt;p&gt;
  console.log("Targ value:", event.target.value); //undefined for h1
  // so you see the target.type is not valid for h1
  // switch (event.target.type) {
  switch (event.currentTarget.tagName.toLowerCase()) {
     /* this needs updates/will not work as it is here need to check for input as tagName then input type for the type="number" etc. */
    case 'number':
      value = parseInt(event.target.value);
      break;
    case 'file':
      value = event.target.files[0];
      break;
      //  case 'contenteditable':
    case 'h1':
      value = event.currentTarget.textContent;
      // value = event.target.innerHTML; // see security warning: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML
      // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML#security_considerations
      break;
    default:
      value = event.target.value;
  }
  //  dot.str(event.target.name, value, tmp);
  //  setValues(tmp);
}

let hedit = document.querySelector('h1.findme');
hedit.addEventListener('input', handleChange);
document.querySelector('input[type="text"].enterme')
  .addEventListener('input', handleChange);
```

```css
.findme {
  caret-color: red;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="findme" contenteditable="true">Howdy</h1>
<input class="enterme" type="text" value="my default" />
```

Comment: This helped point me in the right direction. I've updated my question above with what I've used instead. The problem I'm now encountering is I can't seem to find a way to restrict the input to only numbers (0-9) while still allowing for SELECTALL (CTRL/CMD + A).

Comment: You have changed your question entirely from the original.  Perhaps post a NEW question for that specific new issue rather than continued updates since it will likely not get the attention it needs as an updated question.

Answer (score 0):

From the docs, [Event: type property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/type):

> The type read-only property of the Event interface returns a string containing the event's type. It is set when the event is constructed and is the name commonly used to refer to the specific event, such as click, load, or error.

So, in your case, the event listener is added to `onInput` meaning the type of the event is `input` not `contenteditable`. You just need to change the `contenteditable` case to `input`, then it should work.

Comment: The problem isn't that it's not triggering the correct case, it's not reading anything useful off of `e.target`. In order to update the correct value, I need to be able to access `e.target.name` which is showing up as undefined.

Comment: Ah, I see. That's because `name` attribute is not a valid attribute for`h1` so although it's rendered in the DOM `<h1 name="name"` the event.target.name is still `undefined`. You can try adding another data attribute  `<h1 data-name="name" name="name"` and log it on input `console.log(e.target.dataset.name, e.target.name)`, you'll see it logs `name undefined`